# Extract first object from array with es6 array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have this code to get an array of one object:

```
let selectedShop = initialResultsState.get('products')
        .filter(product => product.shop.selected)
```

`console.log(selectedShop)`

result:

[image]

Can I extract the object from the array in the same operation by stringing another es6 array method to the end of `filter`, rather than doing `let newVariable = selesctedShop[0]`?

I tried to string this to it:

```
.map(x => {return { shop: x.shop, products: x.products }})
```

but it is still an array of one object because map always returns a new array.

Comment: _"rather than doing `let newVariable = selesctedShop[0]`"_ --- what's wrong with doing that?

Comment: try `.shift()` or `[0]` at the end ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Two basic ways:

#### First way is shift'ing:

Array method, you can use `Array.prototype.shift()`.

```
let selectedShop = initialResultsState.get('products')
    .filter(product => product.shop.selected)
    .shift();
```

#### Second way is an assignment:

You can do this, by [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Destructuring_assignment). In your case:

```
let [selectedShop] = initialResultsState.get('products')
    .filter(product => product.shop.selected);
```

This is available in ES6, supported in major browsers without transpiling.

---

But you could see another approach, in answers (Mikael Lennholm's answer) is `Array.prototype.find()`. This can be more performance-effective.

Comment: `pop()` returns (and removes) the last and not the first item. `shift` gets (and removes) the first one.

Comment: I'd actually advise to use `find()` instead as this approach tends to waste time and memory on filtering all matching elements first to deliver only one of them. Those iterator methods are fancy, but they tend to ignore frequent waste of memory and time.

Comment: @cepharum yes, but question was `Extract first object from array with es6 array methods` so I did not recommended `Array.prototype.find()`

Comment: @DanielMizerski no problem, your approach is fine, but if someone's reading your answer (the preferred one) it would be helpful to see downsides of this approach and get a hint to stick with the one given by mikael-lennholm below.

Comment: @cepharum I will reference MikaelLennholm approach

Answer (score 5):

How about using the `find()` method instead of `filter()`? `find()` always return a single item, not wrapped in an array, unless it doesn't find any item, in which case it returns `undefined`

```
let selectedShop = initialResultsState.get('products')
    .find(product => product.shop.selected)
```

It's also a lot more efficient since it actually stops iterating over the array as soon as it has found an item. `filter()` will always iterate over the entire array which is a waste if you're only interested in the first relevant item anyway.